# How to change part of URL with PHP function?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the scenario:

1. I am using Wordpress
2. I use a plugin that pulls products from a online seller and displays it on my website.
3. My website is on SSL and the source website has both SSL & non-SSL
4. The image sources can be both:

   http ://somewebsite.com/folder/someimage.jpg

   OR

   https ://securewebsite.com/folder/someimage.jpg
5. I want to use a function in my Wordpress theme (or in the plugin itself) that will change part of the image URL before the webpage is displayed.

change the first part of the image URL :

***http ://somewebsite.com/folder/***someimage.jpg

and replace it with

***https ://securewebsite.com/folder/***someimage.jpg

I am absolute noobie with php and wordpress and am learning from all the Guru's here. Would be great if the the answer can be detailed please.

The problem is to solve 'Mixed content' warning from Google chrome.

I did see this piece of code somewhere (on some forum) so I guess something like this should work for my site as well.

---

```
function rewrite_image_for_https(&$image_url) {
  // Determine if site is being accessed by HTTPS
  $secure = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? TRUE : FALSE;
  if ($secure) {
    // Strip off protocol, and change protocol and domain to point at HTTPS image
    $url = str_replace('http://insecureimagecource', '', $image_url);
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $url[0] = 'https://secureimagesource';
    $url = implode('/', $url);
    $image_url = $url;
  }
}
```

---

I have also tried the below, nothing works :-( Please help

```
<?php

function rewrite_image_for_https () {

$url = preg_replace("/^http://insecureimages", "https://secureimages", $url);

}

?>
```

Tried this too..

```
<?php

str_replace('http://insecureimages.com', 'https://secureimages.com', $url);

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried already and why didn't it work? Do you have code to show?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to solve this for example:

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
str_replace('http://somewebsite.com', 'https://securewebsite.com', $url);
```

[parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
$secure = 'https://securewebsite.com'.$parts['path'];
```